# Каким членом предложения будет являться выделенная конструкция?

Tags: синтаксис

"Язык так же древен, **как и сознание.**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Со мной будут спорить, но всё же считаю, что конструкция КАК И СОЗНАНИЕ - это неполное придаточное предложение, которое относится к слову ТАК в главном предложении. Ср.: Язык так же древен, как (древне) и сознание. 
Здесь возможна вставка сказуемого, а это уже признак того, что перед нами предложение, а не сравнительный оборот. 
Поэтому "сознание" - подлежащее в неполном предложении.

Об этом, в частности,  говорится и в статье ***Николенковой Н.В.* "Знаки препинания при «как» и синонимичных союзах. Вопросы теории и практики":** 
"А может быть и так, что придаточное – неполное предложение с отсутствующим сказуемым. В этом случае может возникнуть путаница придаточной части и сравнительного оборота: *Мальвина жила в маленьком домике на опушке леса одна, как фея в волшебной стране.* В этом случае сказуемое восстанавливается по смыслу, на него также указывает обстоятельство места, которое обычно зависит именно от сказуемого. Такие неполные придаточные часто путают со сравнительными оборотами, которые лишены сказуемого и тех членов, которые от него зависят: *Каждое утро Мальвина, как лесная фея, выходила в сад и начинала готовить завтрак.*"

Очень интересно ваше мнение.

**Дополняю** ответ, в котором я уже не сомневаюсь.   
Сравним два предложения: ***Язык древен, как и сознание. - Язык так же древен, как сознание.***
В первом предложении "как сознание" - обстоятельство, выраженное сравнительным оборотом, КАК - союз.  Во втором предложении в первой части ТАК - обстоятельство, а КАК во второй части  - это уже не союз, а союзное слово (наречие -обстоятельство), которое входит в группу отсутствующего сказуемого и зависит от него. Следовательно,  "как и сознание" в спорном предложении - это неполное придаточное со значением сравнения и меры.

Comment: Мнение такое. 
Сказать "их часто путуют" и не сказать, как различить, - это все равно что ничего не сказать.
Сказеумое можно вставить абсолютно в любой сравнительный оборот с "как". Чем "как [жила] фея (в волшебной стане)" отличается от "как [выходила] лесная фея" я не вижу. Разве что наличием "волшебной страны". Но тогда так приямо и надо сказать, что любой распространённый сравнительный оборот по мнению г-жи Николенковой надо считать неполным придаточным, -  и вся недолга.

Answer (score 1):

С интересом прочитал ответ Екатерины, но не лежит душа к этому суждению. Сравнительный оборот все же не неполное предложение, а член предложения. Существуют еще и сравнительные придаточные предложения. Сравнительный же оборот часто выступает в роли обстоятельства, но в данном предложении, как мне думается, сравнительный оборот является частью подлежащего или однородным подлежащим по отношению к первому подлежащему "язык": язык, как и сознание, древен = язык и сознание древни. Меня в этом случае смущает только единственное число сказуемого, но это обусловлено особенностью конструкции предложения.

Добавления после одного из комментариев.
     Никак не могу забыть случай, которому лет 30. Я тогда был в Москве на курсах повышения квалификации. На последнем занятии руководитель курсов попросила слушателей высказать свое мнение об организации учебы, дать оценку работе куратора группы. И вот я, молодой, прямой и амбициозный, встал и начал по пунктам критиковал пожилую даму, которая организовывала занятия для нашей группы. Мол, и то не так, и это не четко, и здесь недоработки, и там проколы... Запомнилось, как после моего обличительного выступления одна из коллег шепнула мне: "Тебя, наверное, в детстве много обижали, поэтому ты такой злой..." Эта фраза запомнилась надолго.

Comment: "Душа не лежит" - это сильный аргумент в терминологическом споре.

Comment: В Ваших комментариях, уважаемый, я не раз встречал нечто подобное. Правда, там говорилось не о душе, а некоих иных субстанциях типа интуиции, настроения, чувства и т.д. Конечно, "душа не лежит" - это не аргумент. Но есть же всетаки такая вещь, как чувство языка или речи

Comment: Впервые нажал курсор, не заметив ошибки, точнее опечатки в слове "все-таки". Прошу у всех прощения.

Comment: В моих комментариях, уважаемый, вы регулярно встречаете даже то, чего там отродясь не водилось. Но все-таки одно дело высказывать мнение как мнение при обсуждении, скажем, стилистики, совсем другое - выдвигать это мнение как аргумент в споре *терминологическом*.

ЗЫ Опечатки можно и нужно править. Если это опечатка, а не повод похвалить себя за "первый раз".

Comment: @behemothus, опять кошачьи повадки? Коготки выпускаете? Ну есть у человека душа и она не лежит. Чего уж к ней цепляться...

Comment: Я не стал бы цепляться к самому образу мысли, но вы же монимаете, что спор о деффинициях сродни спору о вкусах. А уж если и вести его на уровне нравится не нравится... ну вот скажу я, что мне "не нравится" теорема Пифагора.

Comment: А насчет "повод похвалить себя" - это тоже по поводу дефиниций?  

Если Вы скажете, что Вам не нравится теорема Пифагора, я просто промолчу. Или пошучу. Неужели Вы можете себе представить, что я (или еще кто-то) ввяжется в дискуссию?

Comment: >А насчет "повод похвалить себя" - это тоже по поводу дефиниций?  
  
Нет, это по другому поводу. И что с того?


>Если Вы скажете, что Вам не нравится теорема Пифагора, я просто промолчу. Или пошучу.   
  
Очень жаль. Молчание - знак согласия. Что подумает читающий о пишущих, я опускаю.    
  
>Неужели Вы можете себе представить, что я (или еще кто-то) ввяжется в дискуссию?  
  
Я не заморачиваюсь подобными "представлениями". Если человек сморозит глупость на форуме (хотя и в реале тоже), я обычно говорю об этом.

Comment: Зануда ...

Answer (score 1):

Я тоже считаю, что здесь сравнительный оборот и это простое осложненное предложение, а не сложное. Наличие опущенного сказуемого доказывают обстоятельства или дополнения, от него зависящие. В противном случае это оборот, а не придаточное. В приведенной цитате Николенковой объяснено все понятно. *Мальвина жила в маленьком домике на опушке леса одна, как фея* ****в волшебной стране**. **Обстоятельство**  "В волшебной стране" **может зависеть только от сказуемого, оно доказывает наличие сказуемого. Здесь действительно неполное придаточное. В предложении *"Каждое утро Мальвина, как лесная фея, выходила в сад и начинала готовить завтрак."* в обороте** "как лесная фея"** нет обстоятельств или дополнений, значит и сказуемого здесь нет. Это простое предложение с обстоятельством сравнения (сравнительным оборотом).

В предложении *Язык так же древен, как и сознание* в части после запятой нет обстоятельств или дополнений, значит и сказуемого нет. Это простое предложение. Классическое определение сравнительного оборота - обстоятельство сравнения,которое вводится сравнительными союзами. Здесь же, на мой взгляд, есть значение и сравнения, и значение меры и степени одновременно.

Екатерина, почитайте,ещё, пожалуйста, [здесь](http://www.licey.net/russian/syntax/r2_2_3_1) и [здесь](http://www.gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part5.htm)

Comment: >Обстоятельство "В волшебной стране" может зависеть только от сказуемого  

Вообще-то как минимум с неменьшим основанием это можно счиать дополнением. Ну да не суть важно. 
Почему, чем бы оно ни было, может зависеть *только* от сказуемого?

Comment: 1.Вряд ли Вы зададите вопрос к словоформе "в стране" - "в чем?", "а "где" - это все-таки обстоятельство. 
2. Да, если брать все случаи обстоятельств, то, конечно, оно может быть выражено , например, наречием и зависеть от прилагательного или другого наречия. Я отвечаю ближе к конкретному предложению. В примере  У Екатерины обстоятельство места, оно, как правило, зависит от глагола-сказуемого или от члена предложения, выраженного отглагольным существительным.

Comment: 1. Об этом профессора спорят.  
  
Стремление распределить всё многообразие синтаксических связей слов по трём рубрикам второстепенных членов предложения (определение, дополнение, О.) в сочетании с отсутствием строгих критериев для такого разграничения приводит к колебаниям в классификации, в результате чего либо допускается двоякое толкование одного и того же явления, либо признаётся наличие переходных случаев, что делает нестрогими сами основы классификации.  
http://russkiyyazik.ru/553/  
2. Я - нет. Но "я" - не критерий.

Comment: Уважаемые коллеги, меня смущает факт, что конструкция "КАК и СОЗНАНИЕ" относится к слову ТАК (древен). Как древен? В какой мере? степени? То есть от него обычно зависят придаточные меры, степени, образа действия... А сравнительный оборот? Могут ли у него быть оттенки значения? Он же используется только для сравнения: в сравнении с чем? подобно чему? 
Лара, спасибо Вам, сейчас займусь Вашими ссылками.

Comment: Да! Чуть не забыла! В предложении "Язык древен, как сознание" я, ни секунды не сомневаясь,  выделила  бы "как сознание" обстоятельством, так как это чистое сравнение.

Answer (score 0):

Это обособленный сравнительный оборот (даже не знаю, справедливо ли его считать "членом предложения" - это уже "вопрос по понятиям").

Это никак не неполное придаточное.
*Промежуточное положение между придаточным сравнительным и сравнительным оборотом занимает неполное сравнительное придаточное предложение, в котором представлены состав подлежащего и состав сказуемого без самого сказуемого, восстанавливаемою из основной части предложения, или только сказуемое с зависимыми словами. * 
Словарь-справочник лингвистических терминов. Изд. 2-е. — М.: Просвещение. Розенталь Д. Э., Теленкова М. А.. 1976.

В нашем примере отсутствует не только само сказуемое, но и его состав.

*Состав сказуемого (зависимый состав). Сказуемое вместе с зависимыми от него второстепенными членами предложения.*
(там же)