# Сравнительный оборот — какой член предложения?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, сравнительный-оборот, члены-предложения

Каким членом предложения является сравнительный оборот или он вообще им не является? Помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**ВМЕСТО ВСТУПЛЕНИЯ**

Можно ли  вообще говорить о том, **каким членом предложения** является сравнительный оборот, и уж тем более говорить об этом **однозначно?**

Вероятно, это принято в школьной практике, но по сути вопрос остается открытым.

Надо сначала четко определить, какие члены мы называем **второстепенными.**   Обычно второстепенные члены – **эти присловные распространители,** которые определяются на уровне исходных **словосочетаний**.

Безусловно, сравнительный оборот **присловным распространителем не является**, даже если он не обособлен, так как в нем присутствует элемент синтаксической связи – **союз КАК**.
Сравнительный оборот – спорная синтаксическая конструкция, взгляды на нее неоднократно менялись. Одно время считалось, что это неполное придаточное, потом его стали включать в состав простого предложения, а в настоящее время частично возвращаются к сложной трактовке.

В любом случае считается, что полностью приравнивать оборот к обстоятельству нельзя. Рассмотрим такой пример: ***И гневом, словно мраком ночи, покрылось старое чело***. Сравнение, с одной стороны, относится к  определенному слову (*покрылось словно мраком*), это **подчинительная** связь, но между предметами сравнения (*гневом, слово мраком*) связь имеет **сочинительный** характер.

Получается, что мы можем только **условно** определить,  какие отношения выражает сравнительный оборот – объектные, признаковые или обстоятельственные.  Тогда и постановка конкретного вопроса  для определения его роли в предложении также выглядит весьма условно.

**ОТВЕТ**

Конструкции сравнительных оборотов бывают самые разнообразные.

1. В  одних случаях определить характер оборота  несложно, например:

Сказуемое: Заря как пожар на снегу. Тучи как свинцовые.

Обособленное дополнение:  Россия в снег, как в серебро, одета.

Обособленное обстоятельство: В очах, как на небе, светло.   Ноги ступают неслышно, как по ковру.

Обособленное несогласованное  определение: Воздух дымился густым, как известковая пыль, светом.

Обособленное согласованное  определение: Перед нами открылся красивый, как нарисованный, вид.

2. Трудности могут возникнуть,  когда мы имеем **трехчленную конструкцию**, в которой сравниваются два предмета (в  форме И.п.)  через  действие или признак.

При сравнении **через действие**  оборот обычно имеет обстоятельственное значение и относится к сказуемому, но не все случаи в этот стандарт укладываются, иногда сравнение можно отнести к подлежащему и считать приложением. При сравнении **через признак** также сложно задать обстоятельственный вопрос.

2.1. Обособленное обстоятельство  (как правило)

Картечь, как град (= градом, часто), посыпалась со всех сторон.

Он  проспал и мчался теперь на лекцию, как метеор (= очень быстро).

2.2. Обособленное приложение (при нестандартных сравнениях) или сравнении через признак

Но, как медуза, невская волна Мне отвращенье легкое внушает (О. Мандельштам).

Она искусно сплела паутину лжи, **как паук**.

Воздух чист и свеж, как поцелуй ребенка.

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы **однозначно** ответить на ваш вопрос, нужно видеть конкретное предложение.

Почему? Потому что в предложении сравнительный оборот может быть:

а) именной частью сказуемого (*Лед* [был] *как стекло*);

б) обстоятельством (*Он проспал, и теперь мчался на лекцию, как метеор*);

в) определением (приложением)
*Но голос мой, как воздух свежий,

Пропел давно, замолк давно

Под тростником у прибережий.*
А. Блок

Чаще всего, конечно, сравнительный оборот является в предложении **обособленным обстоятельством**.
Необходимо разграничивать сравнительные обороты и придаточные предложения сравнения — в сравнительном обороте не может быть сказуемого и второстепенных членов, связанных со сказуемым.

*Она искусно сплела паутину лжи, **как паук*** (сравнительный оборот).
*Жгучее солнце висит в небе, **как паук*** [висит] ***в паутине*** (неполное придаточное предложение сравнения).

[Сравнительный оборот](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/sintaksis/sravnitelnyi-oborot-primery.html#:%7E:text=%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%20%E2%80%94%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20c%20%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%2C%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0,%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%82%20%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%2C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F.)

**P. S.** Бурная дискуссия по схожему вопросу (*Язык так же древен, как и сознание*):
[Каким членом предложения будет являться выделенная конструкция?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/10243/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/10253#10253)

Comment: Вот я не могу понять, разве в этом предложении (Она искусно сплела паутину лжи, как паук) можно к "как паук" задать обстоятельственный вопрос? Нельзя же спросить "каким образом?"